# Infer type of literal objects union by a field

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have some one-or-the-other properties in an interface. Dividing these properties into two interfaces and then declaring a union type of both seems the way to go.

Please look the following simplified situation where a function expects either a percentage or a fixed value. Adding to each interface a prop that states if its one type (isPercent) and constraining the type to a specific value, allows the logic of the function to detect the type of parameter passed and typescript -amazingly- seems to infer the type too but only.

It's difficult to describe it but I hope the code will give you the idea:

```
interface IPcentFee { isPercent: true, percentFee: number }
interface IFixedFee { isPercent: false, fixedFee: number }

let parm = { isPercent: true, percentFee: 0.15 }

function calculate(parm:IPcentFee | IFixedFee){
    let value = 100, discount
    if (parm.isPercent) 
        discount = value * parm.percentFee  // Here ts infers type of parm being IPecentFee
    else 
        discount = parm.fixedFee    // ts error: Property 'fixedFee' does not exist on type 'IPcentFee | IFixedFee'
    ....
}
```

TS seems to infer the type IPcentFee from the condition `if (parm.isPercent)` but why the else clause does not infer the alternate type?

The sample was analyzed by ts **version 2.9.1**

Comment: What version of typescript is this? I ran your code on my machine and it picks up fixedFee

Comment: Strangely, `(parm.isPercent == true)` fixes the type inference error for me (TS 2.6.1).

Comment: I am using TS 2.9.1, I will update the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty interesting indeed.

Look at this:

```
interface IPcentFee { isPercent: true, percentFee: number }
interface IFixedFee { isPercent: false, fixedFee: number }

let parm = { isPercent: true, percentFee: 0.15 }

function calculate(parm:IPcentFee | IFixedFee){
    let value = 100, discount
    if (parm.isPercent === true) // Comparing to literal `true`
        discount = value * parm.percentFee
    else 
        discount = parm.fixedFee // it works!
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IPcentFee%20%7B%20isPercent%3A%20true%2C%20percentFee%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20IFixedFee%20%7B%20isPercent%3A%20false%2C%20fixedFee%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20parm%20%3D%20%7B%20isPercent%3A%20true%2C%20percentFee%3A%200.15%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20calculate(parm%3A%20IPcentFee%20%7C%20IFixedFee)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20value%20%3D%20100%2C%20discount%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(parm.isPercent%20%3D%3D%3D%20true)%20%2F%2F%20Comparing%20to%20literal%20%60true%60%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20discount%20%3D%20value%20*%20parm.percentFee%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20discount%20%3D%20parm.fixedFee%20%2F%2F%20it%20works!%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Just changing the `if (parm.isPercent)` to `if (parm.isPercent === true)` does the job and the type is narrowing in every branch as intended. I have to admit I'm not totally sure why the other way doesn't work. I guess it is due a `truthy`/`true` discrepancy... But, as have shown, you can compare to the literal value so you don't need to assert manually.

**Update:**

In fact it looks it is due a discrepancy, but not for `truthy`/`true` but `falsy`/`false`. If you enable the `strictNullChecks` flag your code just works.

If `strictNullChecks` is not enabled every type is *nullable* by default, so you can still need to check `isPercent` to `null`/`undefined`. Enable that flag make every type *non-nullable* by default so in fact the only two possibilities (as for the type checking) are `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Union types with Interfaces are funny in Typescript, and generally need to have common properties for you to directly reference them. So your interfaces could be:

```
interface IPcentFee { isPercent: true, fee: number }
interface IFixedFee { isPercent: false, fee: number }
```

And access with:

```
discount = value * parm.fee
```

`fee` can be common, because you're checking on the common property `isPercent`.

Alternatively, you can cast in your else clause to the following, which throws no errors.

```
discount = (<IFixedFee>parm).fixedFee
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IPcentFee%20%7B%20isPercent%3A%20true%2C%20percentFee%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20IFixedFee%20%7B%20isPercent%3A%20false%2C%20fixedFee%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20parm%20%3D%20%7B%20isPercent%3A%20true%2C%20percentFee%3A%200.15%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20calculate(parm%3AIPcentFee%20%7C%20IFixedFee)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20value%20%3D%20100%2C%20discount%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(parm.isPercent)%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20discount%20%3D%20value%20*%20parm.percentFee%20%20%2F%2F%20Here%20ts%20infers%20type%20of%20parm%20being%20IPecentFee%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20discount%20%3D%20(%3CIFixedFee%3Eparm).fixedFee%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20ts%20error%3A%20Property%20'fixedFee'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'IPcentFee%20%7C%20IFixedFee'%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D)